# MongoDB aggregate from adjustable foreign collections

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

My documents in the orders collection has `_client` key, which is an ObjectId references to another entity in another collection.
The collection could be **organization** and could be **users** - I mean - it's variable collection.
I want to tell Mongo to lookup if the _client id is found in both collections.

```
{
    $lookup: {
      from: "users", // could be "organizations" 
      let: { "client": "$_client" }, // could be "_organization"
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$_id", "$$client"] }}},
      ],
      as: "client"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$client"
  },
```

I have tried to just set up two look ups, once for **_client** and one for **_organization** however when there one of them is missing, I just got no results at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#unwind-aggregation) filtered out the documents where arrays are empty and do not contain any element.

So, You have to use [**`preserveNullAndEmptyArrays`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind) and set it to `true`

```
{ "$unwind": { "path": "$client", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true }}
```

and same for the or `organizations`

```
{ "$unwind": { "path": "$organization", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true }}
```